# How does the TargetResponseTime AWS Cloudwatch metric work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elb

I have a Tomcat application deployed on EC2, behind an application load balancer. The load balancer has an alarm set for `TargetResponseTime`, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5hHx.png).

The metric says the response time cannot be greater than 1 ms - but when I look at the chart, there are multiple instances of the target response times going over 2000 ms [continuously for 5 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4MS.png).

And yet, the alarm only goes off sometimes and not all the time.

1. Why is the alarm not going off almost all the time?
2. Can someone explain target response time better than [the explanation given in the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html)?
3. Is 1 ms a realistic target response time to measure if I see sometimes the values going to 5000 ms?
4. I see the message in pic 1 "Value will be converted to match cloudwatch metric units". And yet in cloudwatch, the alarm generated is of unhealthy host with no mapping to the 1ms value

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled onto this from searching around for my own problems.  I know this is old, but I thought I should post some info for others that come across this.

If you follow through to the [ELB access log definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) of `target_processing_time`:

```
The total time elapsed (in seconds, with millisecond precision) 
from the time the load balancer sent the request to a target 
until the target started to send the response headers.
```

This is a pretty dumb statistic for Amazon to offer, and isn't *really* that useful.  If your web app is unbuffered and spits out response headers right away, this value will be consistently low and have little bearing on your real performance.

A better method is to track your own delivery times within your app and publish custom metrics for them.

Comment: Definitely not a dumb stat because that helps us understand if the loadbancer is taking too much time to send a request to the target. Sometimes, we have one load balancer that is serving traffic to multiple targets with each target hosting multiple web applications. if the stat show high, we should consider moving that specific web app to a different load balancer to separate it from all other traffic and to further troubleshoot.